# No installation steps when Installing CentOS 6.4 on VMware Fusion

Tags: linux, centos, system-installation

This is my first real day on using linux. I'm following a book guide.

I installed CentOS 6.4 on my mac using VMWare Fusion. However, during the installation, it did not guide me through the installation steps (e.g., choosing software selection like Server, Server-GUI, Desktop-KDE, or choosing `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var` and other stuff). I just directly, got my CentOS up and running.

Any one know how can I get this installation steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you accidentally burned the LiveCD version of CentOS. Basically, that means you're booting into a graphical environment from the CD/ISO and haven't actually installed it yet. A LiveCD environment is used to either troubleshoot an existing Linux system (using the boot environment to issue commands from), or to "test drive" the OS without committing yourself to the process by modifying the hard drive

You may want that if you want to play around with CentOS a little bit before installing it for real (personal preference on your end).

When you do want to install it you'll have to [pick a different ISO](http://centos.arcticnetwork.ca/6.4/isos/x86_64/) from one of their mirrors. I use the two full DVD images (that you get from the torrent file). You usually only actually need the first DVD ISO, but that depends on what software you pick during the install).

Comment: Thank! So I have to download CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD1to2.torrent?

Comment: Yeah, after you open that .torrent file in a client that supports bit torrent, it'll start a download of the two ISO's that you need to actually install the OS with.

Comment: Just got back home,  I just checked, I actually downloaded and installed this version on my VMWare Fusion.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just noticed that I accidentally enabled the `easy installation` in VMWare. Thank you for your help! I will mark it as correct :)